# Android Studio - java-классы превратились в xml-код

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Товарищи, нужна помощь. У меня в проекте внезапно активити превратились в куски xml-кода и проект не билдится. Я даже не могу понять, что я такое сделала, чтобы это произошло. 
Теперь мои активити выглядят примерно так:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7-28.0.0">
    <ANNOTATIONS>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.aar/dbd870b8f46716c9fffb64ddee19b123/annotations.zip!/" />
    </ANNOTATIONS>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.aar/dbd870b8f46716c9fffb64ddee19b123/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.aar/dbd870b8f46716c9fffb64ddee19b123/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

build.gradle стал выглядеть так:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.android.support:documentfile-28.0.0">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/documentfile-28.0.0.aar/a540a8aae6953117ba564277ac4adeb7/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/documentfile-28.0.0.aar/a540a8aae6953117ba564277ac4adeb7/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

второй build.gradle содержит слеующее:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.mixmara.servicego"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

Подскажите, что делать?
Я только начала изучать андроид для написания диплома, в нюансах настройка gradle совсем не разбираюсь.

Comment: Я так и не смогла разобраться, что это было. Создала новый проект, перенесла весь сохранившийся код туда. К счастью, в самих файлах код оставался, он просто не отображался в андроид-студии.